# Load Testing asp.nt core app

Tags: jmeter

I have an asp.net project ,which I want to load test with around 100 users at a time , can someone plz tell me how can I do this. I tried jMeter but it seems very difficult to understand as because I m doing this first time..Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create test script. You can do this manually in Jmeter GUI, or you can use [Recording controller](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios) or something like SmartMeter's [Recorder](https://www.smartmeter.io/quick-guide#toc-how-to-record-test-script)

After that, you should have recorded script and you can edit it. Add some neede correlations, special variables, prepared data and so.

Before running the test, change number of threads to 100, setup rump-up time and you can start your test.

I suggest you to try some tutorials about load testing and Jmeter, eg.

- [Tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/)
- [SmartMeter's quickguide](https://www.smartmeter.io/learn#id-quick-guide)
- [Blazemeter's tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-brief-tutorial)